# How to Check view is visible in UIScrollview in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

My code

```
CGRect viewRect = tableAnswerSheet.Frame;
            CGRect mainRect = sv.Frame;

            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(mainRect, viewRect))
            {
                //view is visible
            }else{

            }//view is visible
```

But getting this error.

> The name `CGRectIntersectsRect' does not exist in the current context

Using

> using CoreGraphics;

what is alternative class of **CGRectIntersectsRect** in Xamarin.ios

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is `CoreGraphics.CGRect.Intersects` https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/CoreGraphics.CGRect.IntersectsWith/p/CoreGraphics.CGRect/

```
CGRect viewRect = tableAnswerSheet.Frame;
CGRect mainRect = sv.Frame;

if (viewRect.IntersectsWith(viewRect))
{
    //view is visible
}
else {
      //view is visible
}
```